# Visual Studio Open Prompt Not Showing

Tags: visual-studio

I've been using `Visual Studio` for a long time and as it comes on install, it adds the Open With Code part to your context menu. Recently I went through and accidentally deleted the REG entry for it and I'm not sure how to get it back without uninstalling and installing back as that would be a huge pain.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, you're gonna have to reinstall it.